# Android List View com Layout "Complexo"

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Até hoje eu não havia precisado utilizar layouts que fujam do padrão de um list por exemplo.
Dessa vez, preciso criar um list view com uma espécie de header.
Por exemplo: `[{categorias: [{1, 2, produtos:[{1, 2}]}]}]`
Resumindo, o header seria a categoria e o conteúdo do list seriam os produtos.
Alguma sugestão de como eu deveria montar o adapter?
De preferência utilizando apenas componentes nativos, estou desenvolvendo nativamente.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei o componente correto: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView

att